# HTTP Authentication clear SERVER variables

Tags: php, mysql, http, authentication

I have the following problem:

I use HTTP Authentication to login. I end  the session in php but the variables for user and password still remain without closing the
web browser. Is there a way to clear this variables without closing the web server.

My test site:

```
1.- login.php (HTTP Authentication and mysql users data base);
2.- If ok user and password go to page1.php else kept prompting for user and password;
3.- In page1.php there is a link to logout.php which ends the php session. 
4.- If I click the button back to page1.php it tells me that I am logged out and gives me a link to login.php to login again.
5.- When click the link to login again there is not prompt for user and password it redirects me to page1.php and tells me that I am
    logged in with same user and password as the firs time.
```

Thanks in advance for yor help.

thor6006

Comment: the browser will keep sending the auth/pass for http basic until the browser is told they're no longer valid - e.g. the web server has to send a 401/unauthorized to trick the browser into thinking the credentials aren't valid anymore.

Comment: thanks for your answer I use this: header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"); exit; did not worked

Answer (score 0):

One of the major problems with HTTP Authentication is that there is no correct way to force the browser to log the user out.  Unfortunately, there isn't even a way to do this that works across browsers.

Ideally, you would implement your own authentication system instead of relying on HTTP Authentication.

However, it is possible to get browsers to drop the authentication header via some Javascript.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function logout() {

            var xmlhttp;
            var logout_redirect = "/where/to/redirect";
            var always_200 = "/path/that/will/return/200/OK";

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                // Handle IE
                document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
                window.location.href = logout_redirect;
            } else {
                // Handle other browsers
                xmlhttp.open("GET", always_200, true, "logout", "logout");
                xmlhttp.send("");
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                        window.location.href = logout_redirect;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="logout();">Log out</a>
</body>
```